# Merge different datatypes value into one

Tags: java, string, arrays, long-integer

I have a ByteArray value as `byteData` , Schema Name value as String `schemaName` and Last Modified Date value as `lastModifiedDate`.

```
byte[] byteData = os.toByteArray();
String schemaName = "S1";
long lastModifiedDate = "1379811105109";
```

I need to combine these three values into one with some delimiter so that we can identify each one of those after splitting the values. Meaning make a composite value for these three..

And after combining these three into one. I will store that single value into one of my column. And while reading back, I will split using that same delimeter if necessary.

I was thinking to use JSON but again I need to serialize it to JSON and DSERIALIZE back to get everything from that JSON, which is not what I want. And I am looking for some other approach..

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: If you're interested in the JSON-approach, I can highly recommend the Jackson JSON library: http://jackson.codehaus.org/ . Just put all those values as fields in a class, create an ObjectMapper, and then read/write the data.

Comment: If you serialize/deserialize using JSON or a self-built method, what is the difference? If the options are between those, I would choose JSON at all times which is a well-known and well-implemented way to serialize things across many different platforms.

Comment: The problem is byteArray value that I am getting is from the Avro data serialization format. So in other words, I have a column in which I need to store AvroBinary encoded value which is byte array and its schema name and last mdofied date as well. So all three into single column.. So now if I am thinking to use JSON on top of all these three, I will be doing serializing/deserializing twice. First DESERIALIZE JSON, then deserialize Avro Byte Array value to get the data..

Comment: Why not store the three values in three different columns? That's what columns are for, isn't it? Otherwise you would still have to serialize twice no matter which method you choose to combine into one column.

Comment: I am going to use Cassandra for this use case. So my column family is dynamic which means, I can have as many columns as possible. So for our timeseries use case, it might be possible we are going to have 200 (approx) columns around. So 200 * 3 will be 600 columns. So that's why I was thinking of other ways.. Ok.. So the question will be now.. If I go with JSON route as compared to pipe delimeter route which one will be efficient in terms of serializing/deserializng the data for the first time?

Comment: Your `byte[]` data can be Base64 encoded and store as a JSON string.